# Way to fast change color for group of clusters in Gephi

Tags: cluster-analysis, gephi

After running the cluster algorithm I prefer to set the colors of my own choice.
And I want to highlight only most important clusters. In Partitionig -> Nodes -> Clustering (Chinese Whispers) is a convenient option "All Blacks". But I'm using a black background. Maybe somebody knows where change (in config files or something like that, I don't know exactly) that all nodes will become whites after pressing "All Blacks"?
Or maybe you know a better way to group them and set color.
Now I am using filter portion -> Clustering (Chinese Whispers) -> set clusters -> go to data lab -> create column color and set to white.
But it is not very convenient.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Partition** tab in Gephi. Check the slides [here](http://www.clementlevallois.net/gephi/tuto/en/gephi_tutorial%20foundations_en.pdf) p. 38-40. you can then modify the colours for each partition by right-clicking on each partition color